# Does "be lost in something" have a positive or negative meaning?

Tags: meaning

> I get lost in my job.

What does it mean?

1. I get immersed in my work so deeply even the outside world seems to cease to exist (because I'm concentrating so much on what I'm doing). (Which sounds kind of positive, in general.)
2. Even though I concentrate on my job as much as I can (not paying attention to the outside world), I can't really solve some problems in my work. (Which implies strong negative feelings).

I think the first one's correct, but I need confirmation and/or correction, please.

Comment: Heh. I came up with exactly the same two conflicting interpretations of that sentence. Getting lost in something *usually* has the first meaning, but a *job*? It's ambiguous. Is there more context that might help?

Comment: Curiously no, there isn't. :) Really, it's just this single sentence I was asked to translate.

Comment: In the context of "job" I would assume the second, but if you had said "work" instead I'd've assumed the first. Can't explain why, but it has to do with what "job" versus "work" connotes.

Comment: One word answer is both. Elaborate and it depends on context but it *can* mean either or but doesn’t have to. To give an example I get lost in both programming and reading and this is only good until I ignore other things I have to do or even want to do. For me lost means enjoying it so much I forgot that I am actually a person who is reading. Otoh if I am lost in depression...

Comment: Of course with the actual example you give I can see it both ways even though some might not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first interpretation (becoming immersed to the exclusion of other concerns) is correct, but that doesn't necessarily make it a positive. (The second would probably be better phrased as "I get lost *at* my job".)

The speaker may be referring to "being in the zone", or may be saying "I could get drunk and stay that way, but I've chosen to hide from the harshness of reality in an artificial process instead". One is becoming one with the Zen of creativity; the other indicates a level of dysfunction.

Comment: I get lost in StackExchange. :)

Comment: Actually, "I get lost in my job" could be intentionally ambiguous.